# Frosted glass effect on entire div doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css

I want a div to be completely covered by another layer that looks like frosted glass. The div under the frosted glass will be the background for my responsive website. It can be gradient or just a picture like in my fiddle. I managed to cover the the div with the effect. However there is still a little gap between the edges of the layers but I want the effect to cover the entire div. Thanks.

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422224832140-0e546210efc3?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1950&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}

.blurred-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  left position right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top position bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="blurred-box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix that is set `:after` to be bigger then container:

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422224832140-0e546210efc3?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1950&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}

.blurred-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: -10%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="blurred-box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try to scale a little the blurred image container and hide the overflow on `.bg`:

```
.bg {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-box:after {
    transform: scale(1.08, 1.08);
}
```

and set `padding: 0; margin: 0;` on `body` to get rid of the small offsets. Some styles are redundant. So, my attempt:

```css
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422224832140-0e546210efc3?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1950&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}

.blurred-box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.08, 1.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="blurred-box"></div>
</div>
```